# Chrome Console Errors "Uncaught"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have written a fairly extensive inventory management app in html/and JS.  Have a module for inputting new products and everything working great without any errors.  However, adding last step - a script for posting the data from the form to the database, I get about 80% through the array of collected data and  am then get Uncaught error from console.  There are about 30 fields collecting data, so I will not post the whole script here (it is pretty basic stuff), but the error message is here: (if needed I will post, but really looking for a console interpreter here.

[image]

I just don't know what that stuff means...Can anyone interpret?

Note, the data input that causes the failure is a calculated item price that calculates based on input cost and margin.  When calculated, the price value renders within a dynamically created HTML table.  The calculation works fine and renders as designed.  The problem seems to result from trying to grab the calculated value in order to pass to DB. 
I am grabbing the data from the cell within the table that has the corresponding "id" - just like any other field in the form...  But the result is Uncaught errors with mysterious (to me) meaning...

Comment: Looks like you are working with minified code. Can you get your hands on the original code.

Comment: right...have started combing through errors in the minified code, and not having much luck understanding.  question: there is a lot of code affecting this.  multiple scripts in play.   e.g. calculate the prices of item and variants, display the prices for user in a table, allow user to enter custom price if she wants, grab  both custom and calculated prices to store in DB, post that data to DB.  SO not sure if there's an effective way to post my code without  being abusive...